# How to use ternary operator with map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to redirect mealContainer to Meals for showing details of that data. By the way, I'm using mealDB for the API. But the problem is when I click meal categories div for showing details, sometimes it becomes **null** and sometimes it shows the data. I don't know why it's happened. So I'm trying to show a warning when it will be **null** by using the ternary operator. How can I do that?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Meals from "../Meals/Meals";
import "./MealCategory.css";

const MealCategory = ({ mealCategory }) => {
  const { strCategory, strCategoryThumb } = mealCategory;
  const [mealsContainer, setMealsContainer] = useState([]);

  const handleOnClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const categoryName = e.target.innerText;
    const categoryUrl = `https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=${categoryName}`;

    fetch(categoryUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setMealsContainer(data.meals));
    // .then(data => console.log(data))
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={handleOnClick} className="col py-3 text-center">
        <div className="card d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
          <div className="img">
            <img src={strCategoryThumb} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
          </div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <h1 className="card-title fs-2">{strCategory}</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {mealsContainer.map((meals) => (
        <Meals meals={meals} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MealCategory;
```

Comment: Have you *tried* using a ternary here? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: No, I'm not. Actually, I'm using mealDB API for a project.  I'm wantto show the data when I click the meal category. But the problem is when I click the category sometimes it becomes null then I get an error. And sometimes it shows the data. So I want to show a warning or something like that. Can I use the ternary operator with the map?

Comment: Yes, again, have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes, I try it.  But nothing happend.

Comment: Please show an attempt at solving the problem as a [mcve].

Comment: Try this `{
  mealsContainer?.map((meals) => (
    <Meals meals={meals} />
  )) ?? '⚠️ Show Warning!'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying sometimes you get `null`, so even if you use ternary operator inside `map`, then also you will get error as you can't run map on an array which evaluates to `null`.
Yes, if your concern is how to use ternary operator inside map, then :

```
{mealsContainer ?
mealsContainer.map(meals => <Meals meals={meals} />) : <p>Error loading data!</p>
}
```